# I want to represent the values of the list in Python as a single string

Tags: python

like this...

```
list1 = [apple, banana, tomato, ...]

str1 = 1.\napple\nbanna\ntomato\n ...
```

As a result, I want to make it like this. What should I do?

```
print(str1)

apple
banana
tomato
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
>>> str='1.\n'+'\n'.join(list1)
>>> str
'1.\napple\nbanana\ntomato'
>>> print(str)
1.
apple
banana
tomato
```

or

**Solution 2:**
This directly prints without need of storing:

```
>>> print(('1.'+''.join(['\n'+i for i in list1])))
1.
apple
banana
tomato
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below

```py
>>> list1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'tomato']
>>> "1.\n"+"\n".join(list1)
'1.\napple\nbanana\ntomato'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Hacky way using `str.format()`:

```py
>>> l = ['apple','banana','tomato']
>>> '1.\n'+('{}\n'*len(l)).format(*l)
'1.\napple\nbanana\ntomato\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following:

```py
list1 = ["apple", "banana", "tomato"]
listString = "\n".join(str(eachString) for eachString in list1)

print("1.")  # I have no idea or the context is incomplete as to why you need to output this. But print it anyway.
print(listString, end="\n")
```

**Output**

```py
1.
apple
banana
tomato
```

**Notes:**

1. The purpose of `\n` in listString operation is to make print function re-render the newline of the string instead of appending the newline as is.
2. Parameter `end` on print renders concatenated `\n` from listString.

Comment: Please understand even if the sentence is awkward because I am not good at English.
I'm making a bot of discode, a chat program. Discode API has a function similar to print(). I asked you this question to prevent the chat from being sent separately.
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
list1 = ["apple", "banana", "tomato"]
str1 = "1."
for fruit in list1:
  str1 += "\n%s"%fruit
print(str1)
```

Comment: Try to avoid using string concatenation in a loop. It's very inefficient since memory needs to be re-allocated and every intermediate string needs to be copied in every iteration. Use `join` instead.